# is there any way to return primary key or entity when execute update in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

I am using update statement to modify record using MyBatis(DB is MySQL),I want to return update entity,is there any way to get update entity or primary key to query update entity? This is my update statement:

```
  <update id="updateForFreeSeat" parameterType="com.sportswin.soa.red.envelop.model.entity.RoomSeat">
    update r_room_seat
    set status = 1
    where room_id = #{roomId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    order by room_play_id desc
    limit 1
  </update>
```

I just read insert return select pk using this method:

```
  <selectKey resultType="java.lang.Long" keyProperty="id" order="AFTER" >
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
  </selectKey>
```

How about update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mybatis [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#insert_update_and_delete) you can use `useGeneratedKeys` for update as well as for insert.

Assuming the field and property you want to return is named `id` you can do it like this:

```
<update id="updateForFreeSeat"
      parameterType="com.sportswin.soa.red.envelop.model.entity.RoomSeat"
      useGeneratedKeys="true"
      keyProperty="id">
    update r_room_seat
    set status = 1
    where room_id = #{roomId,jdbcType=BIGINT}
    order by room_play_id desc
    limit 1
</update>
```